# Cache + random + hook_form_user_register_form_alter

Tags: hooks, caching, users

for a captcha purpose, I'm trying to set a random number in the `hook_form_user_register_form_alter`

For example :

```
function my_module_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $random_case = rand(0, 3);
    $form["random"] = array(
        "#type" => "textfield"
        , "#title" => ""
        , "#disabled" => 0
        , "#value" => $random_case
        , "#description" => null
        , "#weight" => -2
    );
}
```

When cache is disabled it's working as intended.

when I enable the cache the random number is always the same until I flush all caches.
I tried to flush cache programmatically, but it doesn't seem to work. What can I do ?

if I put a

```
die($random_case);
```

It's working but I think it's because drupal can't put the hook inside the cache.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the forms cached, it caches the original, unprocessed `$form` array, and the builder functions are not called again.

you can explicitly set cache off by setting `$form_state['no_cache'] = TRUE;`. Note that this has potential to break Ajax forms.

Comment: I found a hack but I wasn't totaly pleased. It was putting   $GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = FALSE; inside the hook_init. I prefer and adopt your way. Thank you.